# Accessing a component's state from another component

Tags: reactjs

Would like a bit of knowledge gain with your help on this one. Just to clarify, I'm still educating myself with Reactjs.

I have two components, `A` and `B`. I need to access `A`'s state from `B`. Is that possible?

```
var A = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
   return {foo: 'bar'}
  },

 ...
});

var B = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
   return {x: 'y'}
  },

 render(){
  var a = <A />;
  var b = a.state.foo; // This was just a guess but I dont understand the docs for something like this.
  return({b});
 }
});
```

In `B`'s component, how to render `A`'s state, which is `bar`? I wish to have two separate components.

I have been reading about `ref` but still can't figure out how to accomplish what I want with refs.

*React version: 0.14.3*

Comment: if Naisheel Verdhan's solution doesn't work for you, consider using React's [context](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

Comment: Im watching the video in the link. thanks. i'll report back after.

Comment: Using context is not suggested always until and unless very necessary as with all global variables. Also if state of multiple components need to be accessed, multiple variables would be needed in context. i.e. this.context.states = [{stateOfA}, {stateOfB}, ...]. Passing by props is always recommended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at the purpose of **state** and **props**. A component's **state is completely internal to a component**. It is never known outside of the component and may/not be passed down to the children components (as props). **Props on the other hand are explicitly public** and are merely consumed by the component. They should be the only means of passing information down to a component.

While designing your components, always consider this that any data required by more than a single component cannot be a state of any one of them. React encourages unidirectional data flow and accessing state across different components violates that, thereby making your components difficult to reason with.

In your case, since B needs to know some information which A has, I suggest something like this -

- A publishes this information to a Flux store at an appropriate time.
- B has subscribed to the same Flux store, it gets notified of this
  information and updates itself.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I'm using Rails so I need to use Flux with Rails for this?

Comment: I don't have experience with Rails framework, but you need Flux definitely.

Comment: Based on your advise, I'll accept this answer and see how to integrate flux with Rails.

Comment: Currently using redux as flux is a bit too complex for me.

Comment: That's a natural evolution :).

Answer (score 3):

@HazardousS and @DERIIIFranz are wrong.

In reply to @HazardousS, just because you need data to go from one component to another does not warrant implementing Flux into your app. You always want to use props, then state, then... Flux. The lesson here is, "Only use Flux if you need to." Pete Hunt, an earlier Facebook-er who worked on React published this last week. It disspells a lot of the hype and misinformation in the React community: https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto

In regards to @DERIIIFranz about using `Context`: DO NOT USE CONTEXT. If you just click on the link the Facebook docs even have a warning for its own feature. It's something cute that the React docs does... they give you a lot of rope to hang yourself with.

It seems like you haven't gone through the React tutorials yet because you're asking basic questions about data messaging. This is something you need to understand in a fundamental way if you want to succeed in React. Put in the time, do the tutorials on the Official React docs page, and get familiar with the "React Way" of doing things. It's weird, and odd... but it'll click if you buckle down and sink in the time to learn the fundamentals.

Comment: Well said and thanks. Ive up voted because Ive found this very useful and educational; also inspiring. You are correct, I have yet to full go through the React docs as yet. Ill definitely sit down, invest time and go through it.

Comment: You bring in interesting point here. Thanks for the link to the post as well. But I disagree on my suggestion being incorrect here as the original ask is to access state across components. Neither props nor state would be the right choice here. If not flux then the other preferred choice would be to expose method in A for B to call to share state. This will no doubt bring in an artificial dependency. I would again argue that taking the common data out of both A and B is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

We have to think of ways to make available the `this.state.somevariable` of `<A/>` inside `<B/>`.

1. If `<A/>` and `<B/>` are siblings of a common `<Parent/>`, the parent can change this state for both `<A/>` and `<B/>` and pass the changed state as `this.props.statevariable` to the children.
2. If `<B/>` can be a child of `<A/>`, `<A/>` can always pass its `this.state.statevariable` as `props` to `<B/>`.
3. If you go through the [Flux Architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html), you can maintain these `variable`s required for rendering inside the `Stores` and access these in as many components as you like.